# What can I use instead of AOT in the following protocol?

Tags: nanotechnology, surfactants

We want to nanoencapsulate our pesticide using the following protocol; but we don’t have AOT surfactant. So, what can I use instead of AOT in the following protocol?

> Sodium alginate solution in water was emulsified into dioctyl sodium sulfo-succinate (AOT) solution in methylene chloride by sonication for 1 min over ice bath. The primary emulsion was further emulsified into 150 mL of aqueous PVA solution by sonication for 1 min over ice bath to form a secondary water-in-oil-in-water emulsion. The emulsion was stirred using a magnetic stirrer, and 50 mL of aqueous calcium chloride solution was added gradually to the above emulsion. The emulsion was stirred further at ambient conditions for 18 h and then under vacuum for 1 h to evaporate methylene chloride.